# Que pasa en cada linea de código?

Tags: c

necesito saber que esta pasando en cada linea de codigo , no logro entender el funcionamiento, se que el programa sirve para elegir la posicion de un bits y de cuantos bits quiero cambiar a partir de esa posicion , si es 0 a 1 y si es 1 a 0; Tras finalizar el debug , me salen los resultados que pongo a la derecha tras //.

````
int cambiarbits(int n , int nPos , int nBit)  // resultado =18 , mascara =14 , bit=2 , var=3
{
    int resultado, mascara, bit,var;
    bit = 1;
    var=0;
    mascara = 0;
    while (var < nBit) // nBit =3
    {
        bit = 1 << (nPos - var++); // var= 3 , nPos =3
        mascara = mascara | bit; // bit =2
    }
    resultado = (mascara ^n); // mascara =14 n=28
    return resultado; // resultado =18
}```
````

Comment: Por favor, pon títulos _relevantes_ a tus preguntas. Además, edita tu pregunta y pon lo que has entendido y lo que no.

Comment: @padaleiana  Ya cambie el titulo, si es cierto que no especifique el problema , no obstante si vas a contestar que ponga lo que entendí , despues de comentar que he revisado la función , he echo el debug varias veces y sigo sin entender el funcionamiento , significa que no he entendido que esta pasando. De todos modos gracias con el comentario , si sirve de ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te explico lo que hace el código que has publicado:

```
int cambiarbits(int n , int nPos , int nBit)  // resultado =18 , mascara =14 , bit=2 , var=3
{
    int resultado, mascara, bit,var; //Declaracion de las variables que vas a usar

    //Inicializacion de las variables (asignar un valor a cada variable)
    bit = 1; 
    var=0;
    mascara = 0;

    //Bucle while (se va a ejecutar mientras que la variable var sea menor que nBit)
    while (var < nBit) // nBit =3
    {
        //Te desplazas  hacia la izquierda, restas nPos a Var e incremtas var
        //No entiendo muy bien esta linea 
        bit = 1 << (nPos - var++); // var= 3 , nPos =3

        //Haces la operacion logica OR entre mascara y bit
        mascara = mascara | bit; // bit =2
    }
    
    //Haces la operacion XOR entre mascara y N y estableces el resultado a ese valor
    resultado = (mascara ^n); // mascara =14 n=28

    //Tu funcion devuevle el valor almacenado en resultado
    return resultado; // resultado =18
}
```

De todas formas te dejo el enlace a una pagina que explica las operaciones lógicas en c para que sepas que hace cada operador:

[Operadores lógicos en C](http://maxus.fis.usal.es/FICHAS_C.WEB/03xx_PAGS/0302.html)

También te dejo un enlace a una página que explica las operaciones lógicas para que las entiendas:

[Operaciones lógicas](https://hetpro-store.com/TUTORIALES/compuertas-logicas/#:%7E:text=En%20resumen%20una%20compuerta%20l%C3%B3gica,las%20anteriores%20y%20sus%20negaciones.)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Aarón , no tenía ni idea que las operaciones logicas de OR y NOR se operaban asi , tampoco sabía a que se debía ese resultado.